# Why is scipy.interpolate.griddata performing poorly?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to use griddata from scipy to interpolate values in a database of airfoil coefficients. Basically, the database has a set of coefficients at various angles of attack and Reynolds numbers and I'd like to interpolate linearly between the given points. But when I plot the interpolation against the original points, they don't line up very well. It almost looks like griddata is only using the outside points to define the interpolation. How to I get it to interpolate using all the points?

Here's the results from on of my datasets (blue is the data and red is the interpolation):

[image]

[image]

This is what it looks like for a different database. Notice how it completely cuts off the arches on the right.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
# Read in file
filename = sys.argv[-1]
data = np.genfromtxt(filename, skip_header=1)
N = data.shape[0]

# Plot CL vs first two dofs
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    ax.plot(data[i,0], data[i,1], data[i,-3], 'b.')
ax.set_xlabel("Alpha [rad]")
ax.set_ylabel("Re")
ax.set_zlabel("CL")

# Get griddata prediction
alpha_max = np.max(data[:,0])
alpha_min = np.min(data[:,0])
Re_max = np.max(data[:,1])
Re_min = np.min(data[:,1])

for a in np.linspace(alpha_min, alpha_max, 20):
    for Re in np.linspace(Re_min, Re_max, 20):
        CL = interp.griddata(data[:,:2], data[:,-3], np.array([[a, Re]])).item()
        ax.plot(a, Re, CL, 'r.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out if I normalize the Reynolds number by `Re_max`, the interpolation works perfectly. Normalization is a good thing.